# Create and Add to collection if not exists sails.js

Tags: node.js, promise, sails.js, waterline

I'm pretty new to [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) as well as node.js so this may not be a Sails specific question, but I've created a User and Tag model such that a User has many tags and vice versa. The relevant attributes of user model are:

```
# models/User.js
tags      : { collection: 'Tag', via: 'users' },
add_tag: function( name ) {
  var self = this;
  Tag.findOne({ name: name })
  .then( function( found ){
    if( found ) {
      sails.log.info('found tag ' + found)
      found.users.add( self.id );
      self.save( sails.log.info );
    } else {
      sails.log.info('didnt find tag, creating with ' + self.id + ' and ' + name);
      Tag.create({ name: name, users: [ self.id ] }).exec( console.log );
    }
  });
},
```

And of the Tag model:

```
name     : { type: 'string', required: true, index: true },
users    : { collection : 'User', via: 'tags' },
```

Now when I run `sails console` I use the following test:

```
sails> var user = null; User.find().exec( function( err, u ) { user= u[0]; });
undefined
sails> user.add_tag('cataclysmic');
undefined
sails> info: didnt find tag, creating with 2 and cataclysmic
```

And there it hangs until I press Enter or Ctrl+C and no Tag is created.

Again I'm very new to Node and Sails coming from a Rails background so it could be something very stupid. Also if I'm not using promises correctly please let me know, since I'm pretty new to those as well.

## Update

Per Travis Webb's suggestion, I tried to convert to `findOrCreate` and it's still not working sadly:

```
add_tag: function( name ) {
  var self = this;
  Tag.findOrCreate({ name: name })
  .then( function( tags ){
    sails.log.info( JSON.stringify(tags) );
    return tags;
  }).spread( function( tag ){ // should get the first matching tag
    sails.log.info( JSON.stringify(tag) );
    Tag.update( { name: tag }, { user: self.id } )
    .exec( sails.log.info );
  }).catch( sails.log.error ); //no errors are logged either
},
```

Using the same `sails console` commands as above to call `add_tag()` I just get `undefined` and none of the log statements are executed. Travis, did I do something wrong in this implementation?

## Final Update

I used Jason's answer below to create my final answer:

```
add_tag: function( name ) {
  var self = this;
  Tag.findOrCreate({ name: name }, { name: name })
  .then( function( tag ){
    tag.users.add( self.id );
    tag.save( sails.log.info );
  }).catch( sails.log.error );
},
```

The reason my code was not showing any errors is that I used a lifecycle callback in Tag.js to increment a priority counter each time it is updated like so:

```
afterValidate: function() {
 this.priority++;
}
```

When I should have been calling the next callback in the chain like so:

```
afterValidate: function( values, cb ) {
  values.priority++;
  cb();
}
```

One of the things you don't think about coming from a Rails background :P

Comment: Have you looked at `.findOrCreate`? https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-methods.md#findorcreate-search-criteria-values-callback-

Comment: @TravisWebb please see the above update. Do you think this has something to do with the many-to-many association between User and Tag? Maybe to do with dominance? I didn't make either dominant since they are not cross-connection relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `findOrCreate` incorrectly.

The function definition is `.findOrCreate( search criteria, [values, callback] )`

You're probably going to need to modify your function to look like:

```
add_tag: function( name ) {
  var self = this;

  //for clarity we won't set the user when creating tags, 
  //instead we'll do it in the callback, so its the same for existing and new tags.
  Tag.findOrCreate({ name: name }, { name: name })
  .then( function( tag ){
    tag.users.add( self.id );
    tag.save( sails.log.info );

  });
},
```

Comment: Tried this...same result, even when I catch the error after the 'then'. The callback never gets called. This is much cleaner that I had though. I didn't see in the docs until you pointed it out that it would return an object if only one was found. Can you explain why you chose to save on self rather than the tag?

Comment: Ok so I realized I had a lifecycle callback in Tag that was halting the callback chain. Once I put the callback in there it's moving on the the actual error. Thanks for the help. I might need some as well on the actual error as well but that's a different question.

Comment: Hey, glad I could help. You're correct, I should have been saving on the tag, not on self. I've edited my answer.